# Deploying Excel 2003 VSTO Workbook using Sharepoint for versioning control

Tags: .net, sharepoint, vsto, excel-2003

I have an excel 2003 vsto workbook that I would like to make available via sharepoint for version control. Ideally it could be checked in/out by non-developers for tweaking excel equations, and I would be able to deploy the compiled dlls somewhere else when I need to update the managed VSTO code. I understand I may need to use some clickonce functionality as well so when a user first views the sheet they get all the necessary full-trust permissioning.

Also, it is my understanding that for a user to use the vsto functionality in an excel 2003 vsto workbook, they must have the compiled dll in thier GAC, is this true? When testing I get trust exceptions otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Setup

1. Create a custom setup project that adds the project output dlls to the GAC.
2. Add excel doc to sharepoint

Client Install

1. Install VSTO Runtime on client
2. Install custom installer
3. View/Check out workbook from sharepoint

I'm open to improvements.